Bitcoins did not arrive at the wallet
bc1qfqdzx2tdmq3gedhqehps7q8xfmjnr9up9m4wfd адрес
Хеш: d879b67bcb3bb0e2bbf9e6cd8db6b1cdbd041fc6cce25cae66ac8e6cc5154d1b
Bitcoins did not arrive to the wallet, the correct address was synchronized, 1395 confirmations, but bitcoin did not arrive to the wallet

This question is similar to: Recipient has “not received” the Bitcoin I sent, but the transaction is confirmed. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Everything looks in order, check this link: https://blockstream.info/tx/d879b67bcb3bb0e2bbf9e6cd8db6b1cdbd041fc6cce25cae66ac8e6cc5154d1b

You can diagnostic what happen on your address thanks to mempool.space https://mempool.space/fr/address/bc1qfqdzx2tdmq3gedhqehps7q8xfmjnr9up9m4wfd
When we look at your address we see that you have 5 transactions.
You receive BTC on this adresse on ‎2024-09-30 15:45:10
But the some BTC was sent :

on 2024-09-30 22:19:19
on 2024-10-01 01:25:41
on 2024-10-01 17:24:03

And now you have 0 BTC on this adresse.

